# What to clear using CCleaner for performance

Tags: performance, ccleaner

I wonder what are the things i should clear using CCleaner for best performance. I see that some of the items are cache files eg. Thumbnail cache, DNS cache. will removing them have any negative performance impact?

Comment: I generally avoid messing with the Registry, and just go with temporary files. Deleting caches is not always advisable because Windows will just rebuild them. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

The [CCleaner Documentation](http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/ccleaner-rules) has information on all of their cleaning rules.

Answer (score 0):

These are the options that I select while using CCleaner. That way I get rid of the junk, while not wiping out my browser history and other details.

[image]

[image]

[image]